# Unpack Values from a UDF in Python Polars

Tags: python, python-polars

```
def do_something(text):
    return {"b": 1, "c": 1} 

(
    pl.DataFrame(
        {
            "a": ["x", "y", "z"],
        }
    )
    .with_columns(pl.col("a").apply(do_something))
)
```

How can I unpack the return of the UDF to seperate columns in the original polars DataFrame? In the example the resulting DataFrame should have the columns a, b and c.

Answer (score 2):

You need to name the expression to stop from overwriting the original `a` column.

Your UDF returns a dict which Polars creates a struct column from.

You can use [`.unnest()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.unnest.html#polars.DataFrame.unnest) to turn a struct into individual columns.

```
def do_something(text):
    return {"b": 1, "c": 1} 

(
    pl.DataFrame(
        {
            "a": ["x", "y", "z"],
        }
    )
    .with_columns(result = pl.col("a").apply(do_something))
    .unnest("result")
)
```

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ x   ┆ 1   ┆ 1   │
│ y   ┆ 1   ┆ 1   │
│ z   ┆ 1   ┆ 1   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The unnest on the dataframe was what I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import polars as pl

def do_something(text):
    return {"b": 1, "c": 1} 

df = pl.DataFrame({"a": ["x", "y", "z"]})

result_df = (
    df.with_columns(
        **{key: pl.col("a").apply(lambda x: do_something(x)[key]) for key in ["b", "c"]}
    )
)

print(result_df)
```

Output

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ x   ┆ 1   ┆ 1   │
│ y   ┆ 1   ┆ 1   │
│ z   ┆ 1   ┆ 1   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```